# Codeigniter's update_batch for POINT type MySQL data type?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, geocode

```
$locations[] = [
                 'id' => $r['id'],
                 'city' => $loc['city'],
                 'state' => $loc['state'],
                 'country' => $loc['country'],
                 'long_lat' => "POINT(".$loc['longitude']." ".$loc['latitude'].")"
               ];

$this->db->update_batch('locations', $locations, 'id');
```

My table has a POINT datatype column for long_lat. The above snippet does not work with the long_lat insertion entry, without it it works fine. For some reason, update_batch cannot handle the POINT() datatype.

Codeigniter doesn't seem to like the POINT type, or its escaping something. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: `'PointFromText("POINT(".$loc['longitude']." ".$loc['latitude'].")")'` ?

Comment: did you `CREATE TABLE my_point (p POINT);`?

Comment: PointFromText does the same thing, no update is made. @Vickel yes the column exists as a POINT type

Answer (score 0):

i can't comment so.. try it like this and it will help if you echo the query and post it

```
'long_lat' => "'POINT(".$loc['longitude']." ".$loc['latitude'].")'"
```